# Launch app via iframe src failed in chrome v56 android

Tags: javascript, android, url-scheme

I try to launch my app via `iframe` `src` and custom url scheme.

**My code can launch my app if using Chrome v55 Android, but has some problems in v56.** In **v56**, it just launches one time, even I refresh my web page. I need to kill Chrome and restart it, but it still launches just one time. I don't know what's wrong.

I know about [Android Intents with Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents).

This is my code:

### HTML

```
<a class="btn">launch</a>
```

### JavaScript

```
document.querySelector('.btn').onclick = function () {
  var iframeNode = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframeNode.style.display = 'none';
  iframeNode.src = 'myapp://..'; 
  // 'myapp:// is my registered scheme, I also try 'intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end'
  document.body.appendChild(iframeNode);
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.body.removeChild(iframeNode);
    iframeNode = null;
  }, 0);
}
```